# Excel VBA - Search + Replace instead of For Each Loop?

Tags: vba, excel

I am looping through a column with ~5000 rows looking for a specific unique record. Once found, I offset and replace it with a value from a range. This is naturally rather resource intensive and I found it to occasionally freeze older machines running the macro.

My idea is now to replace this with a Search & Replace macro but am wondering if the performance is actually faster since the process of checking each cell in range for a value would still be the same?

Here the code I have so far. How would a Search & Replace look like and is worth it?

```
Sub Replace_List()
    Dim rList As Range, cel As Range, n As Long
    Dim fnd As Range
    Dim fndFirst As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings")
        Set rList = .Range("D4", .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each cel In rList
        Set fnd = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Columns("A:A").Find(What:=cel.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
            fndFirst = fnd.Address
            Do
                fnd.Offset(0, 1).Value = cel.Offset(0, 2).Value
                Set fnd = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Columns("A:A").FindNext(After:=fnd)
            Loop While fnd.Address <> fndFirst
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "Replaced all items from the list.", vbInformation, "Replacements Complete"

End Sub
```

Comment: Personally, I find that the .Find method can be really flakey. (How it wraps can be weird. Sometimes it seems to return things in weird order. Yada Yada). So I work hard to avoid using it if at all possible.

You probably could make your original search a couple of orders magnitude faster if you don't get the cell values one at a time, but instead make a single call to get all the values into a memory buffer in one shot, and then loop through those values. Then write that buffer back, again in one shot.

Comment: If there is any way to sort the data and then split it into smaller arrays, you can speed it up immensely. From there, you can just compare to the data on the edges of the array and save a lot of calculations. (e.g. If I'm looking through data from 1 - 10,000 and I sort it numerically, I can then split them into 10 arrays of 1000 each. When comparing, instead of having to do 10,000 calculations, you will just need to do 10 (one for each array to see if it's inside those boundaries) and then 1000 to go through the array, resulting in must greater speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This is **not** an answer, but rather something to ponder, and takes up way too much room for a comment.

This is pretty much the format I use on a "Search and Replace". I'm not sure if this ends up being any faster or not, but as you can see, it's not too different from your "find" statement. For me it works fine, but I'm not looking at thousands of records. Hope this helps you make a decision.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Columns("A:A").Replace What:=myValue1, Replacement:=myValue2, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```